# Proof-verification: Any maximal ideal is radical

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Is the following correct? I couldn't find a statement of this, much less a proof, when searching Google, so I am not sure how else to double-check this.

Also, does anyone know of a direct proof, or does the result depend inextricably on the Law of the Excluded Middle?

> Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of a (commutative) ring $R$. Assume by means of contradiction that $Rad(I) = R$. Then $1 \in Rad(I) \implies 1^m = 1 \in I$ for some $m>0 \implies I = R$. This is a contradiction because $I$ is a maximal ideal, hence proper.
>
> Therefore $I \subset Rad(I) \subsetneq R$ which implies that $I = Rad(I)$ because $I$ is maximal. $\square$

Comment: Yes you are right in your reasoning

Comment: Actually, every prime ideal is radical.

Comment: If your definition of $Rad(I)$ for a proper ideal $I$ was "the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$" then everything would be automatic because $I$ would be one of those ideals. It looks like you are using the $\{x\in R\mid \exists n, x^n\in I\}$ definition though. Using the axiom of choice you can easily prove they are equivalent. But if you are worrying yourself over the law of excluded middle maybe you have a lot of worries about the axiom of choice too...

Comment: @rschwieb That's a really good point (I actually wasn't even aware of the first definition of radical). I don't really care that much about LEM or AoC, but I do try to take them for granted less often after having read a little about synthetic geometry.

Comment: @William As long as you truly have a motive to suspend reliance on either of these things, I don't see a problem with that. But if you are just indiscriminately discarding them without cause, it seems like a bit of an unnecessary distraction. Most mathematicians ever worry about either one.